How can I create an expo app with Javascript?
I am trying to create an expo project with JavaScript, but, when I write npx create-expo-app@latest in the terminal, it creates a project for me with TypeScript.
However, I want it to create a project with JavaScript/JSX.
Here's the file tree:

How can I achieve this?

npx create-expo-app@latest --template and choose a template that doesn't use TS

I got it the correct command would be:
npx create-expo-app@latest --template
and select the blank from the options to get the bare minimum configuration, just like the React Native one with JavaScript.

npx create-expo-app --template blank

This command helps you to install app on basic format which is 'jsx' format.

I read that you can just use the default TypeScript project as a JavaScript one. You just make the JS files yourself.

I got the same problem and i create the project using javascript successfully,
First go to the folder that you wish to create the project in terminal

cd foldername
type "npx expo init"
then type the project name
select the blank template and press enter
then go to project using cd
npm start


npx create-expo-app --template blank

npx create-expo-app

use that without the @latest and you can choose manually how to create your react native
